# Leftist heap is merging VERY slowly

Tags: c++, leftist-tree

My implementation behaves correctly with a small, traceable number of items. This leftist heap takes several seconds to insert 50,000 items when it takes a skew heap a few milliseconds.

So I believe I have the algorithm implemented correctly, but not efficiently.

```
struct Lode
{
    int getRank()
    {
        rank = 1;

        if (left || right)
        {
            int rankL = 0, rankR = 0;

            if (left)  rankL =  left->getRank();
            if (right) rankR = right->getRank();

            if (rankL < rankR)
                rank = rankL + 1;
            else
                rank = rankR + 1;
        }
        return rank;
    }
};

struct Leap
{
    Lode* merge(Lode* x, Lode* y)
    {
        if (!x) return y;
        if (!y) return x;

        if (x->data > y->data)
            swap(x,y);

        x->right = merge(x->right, y);

        x->getRank();
        int rankL = 0, rankR = 0;
        if (x->left)  rankL = x->left->rank;
        if (x->right) rankR = x->right->rank;

        if (rankL < rankR)
            swap(x->left, x->right);

        return x;
    }
}
```

Irrelevent(?) code omitted.

Comment: I *think* that you're recomputing the rank too often for that to be O(lg(n)).

Comment: This question is more suitable for [Code Review - StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the rank calculation, as molbdnilo said. The only calculation necessary is

```
x->rank = x->right->rank + 1;
```

Recursively asking each child node its rank was completely unnecessary and inefficient.